# XeLatex and greek quotation marks

Tags: xetex, punctuation, greek

**Background**: «» are the greek analogues of the English quotation marks "".

**Goal**: To be able to write `"quote"` in my .tex file and have *XeLateX* render it as `«quote»`.

**Minimal test case that fails for me**: [taken from here](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2012-May/023125.html)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
Outside ``english'' environment --

\begin{english}
``Quotes'' -- inside english environment  
\end{english}

\begin{greek}
  ``Ελληνικό'' -- περιβάλλον
\end{greek}

``Ελληνικά''
\end{document}
```

**Output**:

[image]

**System specs**:

```
% xelatex --version
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.6-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2014/dev)
kpathsea version 6.2.0dev
( ... snip ... )
Compiled with ICU version 50.1.2; using 50.1.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.0; using 2.4.12
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.2; using 1.2.2
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.27; using 0.9.27
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.11.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.3; using 1.6.6
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.3
```

**Note**: I already know that I can insert them as unicode characters, yet I'd like to be able to use " " :)

Comment: You could create a mapping (with teckit) similar to tex-text which maps the quote to the greek quotes and then load the greek font as `\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Mapping=tex-text-greek]{Times New Roman}`. But I prefer to use the csquotes package.

Comment: If you have a Greek keyboard, you should just be able to type in the Greek quotes in your UTF-8 source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `csquotes` package. But I wouldn't: use the *real* quotes you want to see.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Times New Roman}

\setmainlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage[autostyle,english=american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}

\begin{document}
Outside "english" environment --

\begin{english}
"Quotes" -- inside english environment  
\end{english}

\begin{greek}
"Ελληνικό" -- περιβάλλον
\end{greek}

"Ελληνικά"
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you want LaTeX to guess the quotes to use based on the text, you're asking too much: LaTeX can't read and doesn't really know languages, it just follows instructions.

[image]

Comment: egreg that's great, how it defaults to greek quotes unless I specifically specify english environment (which I rarely do in my thesis, since it is written in Greek). Upvote & accept! <3

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked!!